# High resolution option not present in Win-7 virtual machine at Mac Retina

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a 13" inch Mac Retina which has high resolution. I have installed Virtual Box then used windows-7 .iso file to configure windows-7 virtual machine. While the native resolution of Mac Retina is about ~2500 x 1920, I can't find any high resolution option inside the win-7 virtual machine. The maximum resolution option available is ~1200 x 800 there.

how can I increase the resolution? (if not equal to native resolution, atleast something higher than 1200 x 800).

Answer (score 1):

Right click and choose properties, go to settings, go to advanced, go to monitor, un-check the "hide modes that the monitor can't display" button, click ok, change to what resolution you want, but keep the default refresh rate unless your monitor supports others, and if you have a graphics card that scales the picture down, it will show the scaled down resolution, unless you don't have the option selected then you just move your mouse around to the edge of the screen to move the visible area around